# Is this considered bad ember architecture design?

Tags: ember.js

I have one rootElement for my entire application which within it is my ApplicationView. Within this application view I have a ContainerView which creates my LeftMenu, RightMenu and Body. Is this a bad design if I absolute position the LeftMenu and RightMenu outside of the rootElement div?

[image: ember design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with this, except that you might run into z-index issues since you are imposing a DOM hierarchy constraint on your positioned views.

Comment: I agree. Can I add, I wouldn't say this is a question of Ember Architecture at all.